# best way to extract in DBF

Tags: foxpro

I have 3 Dbf file with a file size between 2 GB to 1.8 GB each. usually, they give me a list then extract it to the 3 dbf file. I use below code to extract

```
Select * from dfbfile_1 where itemcode in (select itemcode from itemlist) into table tmp_1
Select * from dfbfile_2 where itemcode in (select itemcode from itemlist) into table tmp_2
Select * from dfbfile_3 where itemcode in (select itemcode from itemlist) into table tmp_3
close database all
use tmp_1
append from tmp_2
append from tmp3
```

this method is working but it takes time to extract the data. Is there other work around that is faster my current extraction process.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the subquery, i.e. (SELECT ITEMCODE FROM ITEMLIST) will be executed for each row in dfbfile_1, dfbfile_2 and dfbfile_3. It will be especially bad if there is no index on itemlist.itemcode. So the following may work out better.

Assuming dfbfile_1, dfbfile_2 and dfbfile_3 are the same structure then:

```
Select dfbfile_1.* from dfbfile_1 left join itemlist on itemlist.itemcode = f1.itemcode;
union select dfbfile_2.* from dfbfile_2 left join itemlist on itemlist.itemcode = dfbfile_2.itemcode;
union select dfbfile_3.* from dfbfile_3 left join itemlist on itemlist.itemcode = dfbfile_3.itemcode;
into dbf tmp_1
```

However if this results in tmp_1.dbf being > 2GB then you will get an error. There is no way to get around the limitation that any one file openable by VFP cannot be bigger than that.

Comment: i will try this later and compare to my current process and give you feedback